# Pointer to array conversion

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

8.3.4/8 N3797:

> [Example:
>
> consider `int x[3][5]`;
>
> Here `x` is a 3 × 5 array of integers.
>   When `x` appears in an expression, it is converted to a pointer to (the
>   first of three) five-membered arrays of integers. In the expression
>   `x[i]` which is equivalent to `*(x+i)`, `x` is first converted to a pointer
>   as described; **then `x+i` is converted to the type of `x`**, which involves
>   multiplying `i` by the length of the object to which the pointer points,
>   namely five integer objects [...]

Since the type of `x` is an "array of 3 arrays of 5 integers" we have that x+i too. Assume that `i = 2;`

What is the value of the `x + i` (Call him `arr`) elements after convertion to array of 3 arrays of 5 integers? I mean what `arr[3]` equals to?

Comment: You made it this question pretty unclerar, IMO. `x+i` is `int(*)[5]`, it's value (when dereferenced) being the array object at the i-th index.

Comment: @jrok I do agree that `x + i` has the type `int(*)[5]`. But the standard said that _then x+i is converted to the type of x_, that was to the type `int[3][5]` which itself can be implicitly converted to `int(*)[5]` via array-to-pointer-convertion (Section 4.2 of the Standard).

Comment: Can you please revise the standard reference? 3.8 is "Object lifetime" and there's no 3.8.4.

Comment: @jrok I'm sorry for that typo. The correct reference is 8.3.4/8

Comment: I believe you may have found a bug in the standard. "then `x+i` is converted to the type of `x`" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @FredOverflow Why? I think it makes a sense (formally), but we're  absolutely no need in that because of the array-to-pointer convertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arr[3]` is an array of five integers. The reason is the following:

> When x appears in an expression, it is converted to a pointer to (the
>   first of three) five-membered arrays of integers

this means any use of `arr` in an expression would result in having type `int(*)[5]` (decayed).

For `x[3]`, which is equivalent to `*(x+i)`, you first get x translated into a `int(*)[5]` type and advance it, then you **dereference** (remember the *) that pointer and thus get type `int[5]`.

Unfortunately the pointer pointed to an invalid memory spot and therefore any operation on this array of five integers is undefined behavior / access violation.

I agree that the passage really isn't clear about this, it almost seems the two sentences are one before the other (kinda obscure too).

I would have rephrased it as:

> Here x is a 3 × 5 array of integers. When x appears in an expression,
>   it is converted to a pointer to (the first of three) five-membered
>   arrays of integers. In the expression  x[i] which is equivalent to
>   *(x+i), x is first converted to a pointer as described; after the pointer increment x+i (which in a byte-wise fashion involves multiplying i by the length
>   of the object to which the pointer points, namely five integer objects), x+1 gets converted **to the type pointed by x**
>   [...]

Comment: But the type of `x` is not an array of 5 integers. It's an array of 3 arrays of 5 integer.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv the type of x after the decaying is a **pointer to an array of 5 integers**.

Comment: As far as I've unedrstood you first we perform a convertion of `int (*)[5]` to `int [3][5]`, and then using array-to-pointer convertion perform `int [3][5]`  ---> `int (*)[5]` again. Right?

Comment: The array has type `int[3][5]`, the conversion first converts it to `int(*)[5]` (array-to-pointer). Afterwards you increment this pointer (pointer arithmetic) and you eventually dereference it thus getting an `int[5]`. The passage isn't terribly clear on explaining this.

Comment: Indeed, thank you. The Standard is just pretty unclear in there.